# Evaluating a Triple Integral in Polar Coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to evaluate $\iiint_{E}\sqrt{3x^{2} + 3z^{2}}~dV$ where $E$ is the solid bounded by $y = 2x^{2} + 2z^{2}$ and $y=8$.

My thought was to covert this to polar coordinates using $x^{2} + z^{2} = r^{2}$.  Then the solid would be a cone originating in the $xz$-plane with radius of 0 which stretches along the $y$-axis until it terminates as a circle of radius 2.  So I converted $\sqrt{3x^{2} + 3z^{2}}$ to $\sqrt{3r^{2}}$ to $r\sqrt{3}$ and set the integral up this way
$$\int_{\theta = 0}^{\theta = 2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{r=2}\left(\int_{y=0}^{y=2r^{2}} r\sqrt{3} dy\right) r~dr~d\theta$$ 
which equals $\frac{128\sqrt{3}}{5}\pi$.  But the correct answer is $\frac{256\sqrt{3}\pi}{15}$, which means I'm off by a factor of $\frac{2}{3}$. Any help figuring out what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you say “polar” coordinates, do you mean cylindrical coordinates with $y$ as the axis of the cylinder?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the clarification

Comment: I don't see any reason why you are incorrect. Maybe it's a typo?

Comment: I don't know.  I pulled this off of some online notes with very credible solutions.  But the solution in the notes didn't make the conversion to polar coordinates until after evaluating the inner integral in x and z.  I just converted in into cylindrical coordinates, and am coming up short in my solution.

Comment: Your evaluation of the integral you set up is correct. Either it's a typo in the answer or the set up is wrong somehow.

Comment: The limits of integration of the posted solution were equivalent to y=2r^(2) as the lower limit, and y=8 as the upper limit.  Could this be the source of my error?  If so, I don't understand why this would matter.

Comment: Oh, I see it too. Sorry, I was being careless. Your first integral should go from $y=2r^2$ to $y=8$. I was so focused on the polar conversion that I missed the $y$ integral mistake. Doh.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105962/discussion-between-scentless-apprentice-and-zugzug).

Comment: Can you show how you solved the integrals? The solution with the factor $256/15$ is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each radius $r$, the minimum value of $y$ is $2r^2$ and the maximum value is $8$.

You should be integrating over values $y$ can take. Instead you are integrating over values of $y$ between $0$ and $2r^2$.

Comment: I know you must be right, per my comment above.  But if r ranges from 0 to 2 in the middle integral, doesn't that mean y is ranging from 0 to 8?

Comment: I see now.  Thanks again!  You guys are great.